# Select2: Emptying and loading changed array data, loads old data

Tags: javascript, arrays, jquery-select2

First I loaded the array data by:

```
$("#foo").select2({ data: example });
```

Then I changed the array "example" and wanted to change the select by:

```
$("#foo").empty();
$("#foo").select2({ data: example });
```

But the old select showed up. Any idea why?

EDIT: My array wasnt updated which caused the error.

Comment: If you log `example` before setting it again, does it show the correct content?

Comment: Ah, I realized I had not updated the array, thanks!